# Adding capacitor for faster ADC

Tags: circuit-analysis, time-constant

[image]

Vs = 5V

R1 = 50k

R2 = 7k (adc internal resistor)

C2 = 120pF (adc internal capacitor)

I have a big output impedance as R1 at the output of the sensor and i want to connect it to ADC. But max allowed source impedance is 10 kohm therefore i thought to add C1 to decrease the needed charging time. But i can't figure out the exact timing analysis for this RC circuit. Therefore i can't decide the value of C1. Thanks in advance.

Edit: [pic midrange mcu reference manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31023a.pdf)   In section 23.14 (Design Tips) For faster conversion putting C1 capacitor is advised but exact timing analysis is not given after adding C1.

Comment: Are you concerned with bandwidth or settling time or both? There is not a single time constant with this circuit. Also, the source impedance at DC would be R1+R2 = 57K so you have exceeded your 10K spec.

Comment: i am concerned about both. But more with settling time since the frequency range of the input signal is not given. Specs for source impedance is given as max 10kohm to satisfy the guaranteed timing of the ADC. Since my source impedance is 50kohm i decided to put C1 to charge sampling capacitor(C2) faster. R2 is the internal resistor of ADC. Thanks

Comment: I might be mis-remembering, but I think R2 is effectively in series with a switch, so if C2 >> C1 the effect will be minimal. If it's a 10 bit ADC, then maybe 100nF for C1, but that will reduce the bandwidth to ~30Hz and increase settling time from an input change to ~35ms.

Comment: Note also that errors due to leakage are not improved by the capacitor, only the acquisition time.

Comment: Use an op-amp buffer is my advice.

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clear that R2 and C2 are your model of the ADC input.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably consider this in terms of charge transfer rather than as a transfer function.

When the Sample Switch is closed and Rs/R2 and Csample/C2 are in the circuit, there will be a current through R2 provided by C1 and R1. Because R1 >> R2, most of the current will be provided out of C1.

You need to size C1 so that it will only be drawn down to a voltage you can accept, given its discharge into 120pF. Now, 120pF is really freaking small. I'm not going to sit down an analyze it, but it should barely put a dent in 0.1uF!

You just need to take care and not call for an ADC conversion at a too-high rate, because you need to give C1 a chance to restore the charge it lost during the last conversion.

The trade-off is how long it takes C1 to charge through R1 (which determines the low-pass filter characteristic) vs. how much the voltage sags when you try to take a sample. You should figure out what's most important to you and work from there.

*the >> symbol means 'a lot bigger than'